# What is the best way to transfer images between server and client?

Tags: node.js, ionic-framework, server, transfer

I am making an app with the Ionic Framework. The app works a bit like Snapchat; people can send images to each other.

I am using Node.JS as backend on my server, but I don't know what is the BEST way to transfer images between the client (app) and server.

I have thought about Base64, but don't know if this is the best method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No this is not the best way to do image upload. Base64 is the heaviest way to do such upload.

Use multipart request, it will send your image file in chunks(small parts) to the server.